# Random Perl error occurs when trying apt-get upgrade

Tags: raspbian, apt, perl

As of today, suddenly following error occurred while I tried to execute apt-get upgrade

```
Unrecognized character \xA8; marked by <-- HERE after sys_stat_h<-- HERE near column 15Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.14/AutoLoader.pm line 27. at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/POSIX.pm line 25
```

I would be very thankful for any help!